# Instalação de máquina virtual SAP dando erro em banco MaxDb

Tags: erp

Bom dia nobres mestres da programação, tentando estudar SAP por conta própria um amigo me forneceu uma máquina virtual com SAP instaldo. 
Ao tentar subir o sistema SAPMC o sistema chega a subir e volta a ficar status com uma falha. Em uma ajuda de um amigo, o mesmo pode identificar que o banco MaxDB apresentou problema de comunicação segundo o print.
Alguma luz????[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]